# How to do multiple jQuery Ajax requests depending on eachother?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.11 but what if I want to do several Ajax requests after eachother where they need to wait for eachother, is the only solution then to nest them like this:

```
// Ajax #1 -------------------------------
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "index.json",
  data: { urlVar1:val1,urlVar2:val2},
  success: function(data1) {

    // stuff for Ajax #1 ...

    // Ajax #2 ---------------------------
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: "index.json",
      data: { urlVarA:data1-val1,urlVarB:data1-val2},
      success: function(data2) {

        // stuff for Ajax #2 ...

        // Ajax #3 -----------------------
        $.ajax({
          dataType: "json",
          url: "index.json",
          data: { urlVarX:data2-val1,urlVarY:data2-val2},
          success: function(data3) {

            // stuff for Ajax #3 ...

          } // $.ajax.success #3
        }); // $.ajax #3 -----------------

      } // $.ajax.success #2
    }); // $.ajax #2 ---------------------


  } // $.ajax.success #1
}); // $.ajax #1 -------------------------
```

In real-life practice I need `Ajax #1` to fetch a number of groups... `Ajax #2` should process those groups and get subgroups and `Ajax #3` should get individual lines from these subgroups.

In theory I could probably do these 3 Ajax calls with one call but this is just as much to get the understanding on how this can be done as I think the nested approach quickly gets too messy in my code.

Comment: Try to put them in functions

Comment: You didn't really ask a question, guessing the async is causing you problems. Just specify `async:false` in each `$.ajax` call

Comment: @James no... just no...

Comment: @KevinB I know it makes the browser wait, but he has said he needs to wait for responses to chain the calls. It wont work async.

Comment: yes it will. it will work just fine exactly the way he has it. `async:false` isn't the end-all solution to fixing ajax problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.then will make this much cleaner.

```
// Ajax #1 -------------------------------
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "index.json",
    data: { urlVar1:val1,urlVar2:val2}
}).then(function(data1){
    // Ajax #2 ---------------------------
    return $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "index.json",
        data: { urlVarA:data1-val1,urlVarB:data1-val2}
    });
}).then(function(data2) {

    // stuff for Ajax #2 ...

    // Ajax #3 -----------------------
    return $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "index.json",
        data: { urlVarX:data2-val1,urlVarY:data2-val2}
    });
}).then(function(data3) {
    console.log(data3);
}).fail(function(){
    console.log("something happened...",arguments);
    console.log(this.url)
});
```

Comment: I like this approach but how do I see where the fail has happend? I tried this code and then included a file which didn't exists and it just gave me the 404-page but not in which Ajax scope/call the fail was?

Comment: `this` inside the fail should be the ajax options of the request that failed, from that you should be able to get the url.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
$.when( $.getJSON('index.json', { urlVar1 : val1, urlVar2 : val2 }), 
        $.getJSON('index.json', { urlVarA : data1-val1, urlVarB : data1-val2 }), 
        $.getJSON('index.json', { urlVarX : data2-val1, urlVarY : data2-val2 }) 
).then(function(data1, data2, data3){
    console.log(data1);
    console.log(data2);
    console.log(data3);
});
```

Comment: I need to process stuff in between the Ajax GETs so I cannot use this method as they are all combined together in the `.then` method.

Comment: @JohnMalli oh, sorry.. then this will not work, but you can use the getJSON call instead of ajax. I think it is cleaner.